# How rank-revealing QR factorization determine the rank of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I'm just not sure how to use QR decomposition to determine the rank of a matrix. If $A$ is an $n \times m$ matrix, $A$ could be composed into QR, which is the QR decomposition. But how could we determine the rank of the matrix?

Could someone explain it in detail?

Answer (score 1):

The number of pivots of a matrix is the rank of a matrix. The rank-revealing QR factorization uses a pivot matrix to determine the number of pivots and thereby the rank of the matrix. The pivot matrix is a permutation matrix. This is a feature of rank revealing LU decompositions as [well.](https://www.irisa.fr/sage/wg-statlin/WORKSHOPS/LEMASSOL05/SLIDES/QR/Guyomarch.pdf)

It looks like the following

$$ AE = Q \begin{pmatrix} R_{11} & R_{12}  \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$